# graphs from Altair are not displaying

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

On Ubuntu x64, I just freshly installed Anaconda 3.

I then installed `altair` via `conda` per [these directions](https://github.com/ellisonbg/altair). Then I run the example code:

```
from altair import *
population = load_dataset('population')

Chart(population).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(people)',
).transform_data(filter="datum.year==2000")
```

The code runs, but nothing happens. I expected a page would open in the browser perhaps, like `bokeh` does. To be safe, I also ran `jupyter notebook` in the background and re-running the code - no difference.

Please let me know if there's more information you need about my environment.

Comment: But you did enter the code in notebook, not in the interpreter/ipython, right?

Comment: @cel that was it! Just to confirm, there's no way to do this in the interactive console? I have to work from Jupyter?

Comment: I don't think so. I guess it needs javascript rendering capabilities of a browser.

Comment: Ah understood - feel free to post as an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer yourself. Maybe you can even find a pragraph in the documentation notebooks explicitly stating that it will only work in notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @cel, I found out the code cannot be run in the iPython console from Anaconda - it needs to be run from a Jupyter notebook.

You have to run `jupyter notebook` in the terminal, then create a new iPython Notebook. Once the notebook is created, you can run your code interactively from the notebook.

Comment: I don't get it exactly, I run a jupyter notebook (i am not in the console) inside an Anaconda venv, and it doesnt' display neither. Am I missing something ?