# Altair charts in juypter notebook does not render

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter, vega

I can't figure out what's up in my jupyter notebook.  Vincent and Bokeh work fine, but in trying out Altair, I must be missing something, but I'm not erroring and the online docs don't mention my problem.

This is what I enter (from documentation page https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_aggregate.html )

```
from altair import *
Chart('http://vega.github.io/vega-lite/data/population.json',
    description='A bar chart showing the US population distribution of age groups in 2000.',
).mark_bar().encode(
    x=X('sum(people):Q',
        axis=Axis(
            title='population',
        ),
    ),
    y=Y('age:O',
        scale=Scale(
            bandSize=17.0,
        ),
    ),
).transform_data(
    filter='datum.year == 2000',
)
```

The code executes in my Jupyter notebook with no errors, but also no graph.  I do have vega installed, so that's not the issue.  It's not specific to this graph, other examples have the same behavior.  I'm not sure how to even troubleshoot this!

Comment: Do you use anaconda ? There might be a link according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535357/graphs-from-altair-are-not-displaying. I run into the same problem using Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my problem : [Display plots in jupyter](https://altair-viz.github.io/documentation/displaying.html#displaying-plots-jupyter)

Which points to : [How to install properly `altair` in anaconda and enable `ipyvega`](https://altair-viz.github.io/installation.html#installation)

Install `altair` :

```
conda install altair --channel conda-forge
```

Run this line in command line before launching `jupyter` :

```
jupyter nbextension enable vega --py --sys-prefix
```

Launch `notebook` :

```
jupyter notebook
```

[image: It displays !]

Comment: Hmmm... this did not work for me with OSX and Anaconda... the  command `jupyter nbextension enable vega --py --sys-prefix` resulted in an error `[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[EnableNBExtensionApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--py'`.  The command `conda install altair --channel conda-forge` resulted in an error `Error: Error: post-link failed for: conda-forge::vega-0.4.4-py27_0`.  Might work for others, but not for my environment.